# RPi.GPIO - Callback does not work when using classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

I have the following class:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

class DistanceSensor2:

    def __init__(self, GPIO_MODE, GPIO_TRIGGER, GPIO_ECHO):

        def set_times(channel):
            print("set_times")

        self.GPIO_TRIGGER = GPIO_TRIGGER
        self.GPIO_ECHO = GPIO_ECHO

        GPIO.setmode(GPIO_MODE)

        GPIO.setup(self.GPIO_ECHO, GPIO.IN)      # Echo

        GPIO.add_event_detect(self.GPIO_ECHO, GPIO.RISING, callback = set_times)
```

Then, in my main .py I have:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from DistanceSensor2 import *

GPIO_MODE = GPIO.BCM
GPIO_TRIGGER = 18
GPIO_ECHO = 25

test = DistanceSensor2(GPIO_MODE, GPIO_TRIGGER, GPIO_ECHO)
```

I get the error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PythonHelloWorld.py", line 8, in <module>
  test = DistanceSensor2(GPIO_MODE, GPIO_TRIGGER, GPIO_ECHO)
  File "/home/pi/PythonHelloWorld/PythonHelloWorld/DistanceSensor2.py", line 31, in __init__
  GPIO.add_event_detect(self.GPIO_ECHO, GPIO.RISING, callback = set_times)
  RuntimeError: Failed to add edge detection
```

When I use the code below directly in my main .py, it works.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO_MODE = GPIO.BCM
GPIO_ECHO = 18

def set_times(channel):
    print("set_times")

GPIO.setmode(GPIO_MODE)

GPIO.setup(GPIO_ECHO, GPIO.IN)      # Echo

GPIO.add_event_detect(GPIO_ECHO, GPIO.RISING, callback = set_times)

while 1:
    print("inside while")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Can somebody see where the problem is? I have tried moving set_times() to outside the method as well, it does not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally saw the error. My new code is as follows:

My class:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

class DistanceSensor2:
    def __init__(self, GPIO_MODE, GPIO_TRIGGER, GPIO_ECHO):
        self.GPIO_TRIGGER = GPIO_TRIGGER
        self.GPIO_ECHO = GPIO_ECHO

        GPIO.setmode(GPIO_MODE)

        GPIO.setup(self.GPIO_ECHO, GPIO.IN)      # Echo
        GPIO.add_event_detect(self.GPIO_ECHO, GPIO.RISING, callback = self.set_times)

        GPIO.setup(self.GPIO_TRIGGER, GPIO.OUT, initial = GPIO.LOW )

        while 1:
            print("while")
            time.sleep(1)

    def set_times(self, channel):
        print("channel:", channel)
```

My main .py

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from DistanceSensor2 import *
import sys

GPIO_MODE = GPIO.BCM
GPIO_TRIGGER = 24
GPIO_ECHO = 17

try:
    test = DistanceSensor2(GPIO_MODE, GPIO_TRIGGER, GPIO_ECHO)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
    sys.exit
```